# Is it possible to set OnTouchListener in adapter and call it from the activity where the adapter is set?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, adapter

I'd like to set an OnTouchListener on a relativelayout, which is created by an arrayadapter and sent to a listview. But the code, which will be triggered by the OnTouchListener must be written into the activity, where the adapter is set. Is it possible to set the listener to a view in the adapter, and define (or code) it in the activity?

My adapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendlyMessage> {

TouchInterface touchInterface;
protected AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation( 1.0f , 0.0f );
protected AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation( 0.0f , 1.0f );
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText;
    TextView nameText;
    TextView timeText;
    ImageView imageView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    int position;
}

public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendlyMessage> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

public void setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener touchListener){
    this.touchInterface = (TouchInterface) touchListener;
    viewHolder.relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);

    if (message.getPhotoUrl() != null){
        if (Objects.equals(message.getKey(), String.valueOf(Build.SERIAL))){
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_image_right, null);
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageViewR);
            viewHolder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            viewHolder.timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtimeimg);
            Picasso.with(viewHolder.imageView.getContext())
                    .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else if (!Objects.equals(message.getKey(), String.valueOf(Build.SERIAL))){
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_image_left, null);
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageViewL);
            viewHolder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            viewHolder.timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtimeimg);
            Picasso.with(viewHolder.imageView.getContext())
                    .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
    }
    else if (message.getPhotoUrl() == null){
        if (Objects.equals(message.getKey(), String.valueOf(Build.SERIAL))) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_text_right, null);
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel);
            viewHolder.messageText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            viewHolder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            viewHolder.timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
            viewHolder.messageText.setText(message.getText());
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else if (!Objects.equals(message.getKey(), String.valueOf(Build.SERIAL))) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_text_left, null);
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel);
            viewHolder.messageText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            viewHolder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            viewHolder.timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
            viewHolder.messageText.setText(message.getText());
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
    }
//some other code here
    return convertView;
}}
```

TouchInterface:

```
public interface TouchInterface {
void touch(View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener);}
```

And my activity, where I want to call the listener (its a long code, so I removed some parts, which are unimportant now):

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TouchInterface{

private static final String TAG = "MessageActivity";

public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;

private ListView mMessageListView;
private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
private EditText mMessageEditText;
private Button mSendButton;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
private static DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference2;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
private StorageReference mStorageReference;

private String mUsername;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private String key = Build.SERIAL;

private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
private SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
private String time = sdft.format(new Date());
private String date = sdf.format(new Date());

public View.OnTouchListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    assert toolbar != null;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
    mMessagesDatabaseReference2 = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("touches");
    mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("photos");

    // Initialize references to views
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
    mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
    mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
    List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, 0, friendlyMessages);
    mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
    mMessageAdapter.setOnTouchListener(listener);
//some other code here
}
//some other code here
@Override
public void touch(View.OnTouchListener listener1) {
    this.listener = listener1;
    Log.i(TAG, "touched");
    listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
                    break;
            }

            mMessagesDatabaseReference2.push().setValue(x, y);

            return false;
        }
    };
}}
```

Comment: You should be setting an item click listener on the ListView from the Activity

Comment: I tried that also, but the problem is, if I set the listener on the listview, the scrolling gets buggy, if i swipe, it only moves about 10 dp.

Comment: Please show your code, then.

Comment: Edited my question with relevant code, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly you want to set a click listener on a list element to execute a method of the parent activity (in which I guess you will pass the respective parameters). If I got it correctly you should define a variable in your `Adapter` class of the parent activity type. Something like

```
private MessageActivity activity;
```

and then in your `Adapter` constructor

```
activity = (MessageActivity) context;
```

And then when you set your click listener on the view you should do something like

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             activity.YourOnTouchMethodImplementation();
         }
     });
```

Comment: You're welcome :)! To be honest there is a much better way, on an architectural level, to do it and I thought when I woke up the next morning I wrote this answer :P. Since you have a TouchInterface implemented in the activity you want to execute the code, and this code is implemented in this interface, you can just pass in your adapter's constructor a extra variable, like `TouchInterface touchInterface` , instead of casting your `Context` as a specific type of `Activity` and just write in your on click `touchInterface.Touch();`. If you have time try it out, it's a much better solution.

Comment: I think I'll change the code to this, it looks simpler for me, thanks again :)